# Replacement of matlab find function in python

Tags: python, matlab, python-2.7, numpy

I am trying to find suitable python function to replace matlab `find` in my script and with some google search I see `np.where()` solves the purpose most of the time. But in case of double condition, I have different outputs. Can someone tell me whats wrong with this approach and how to go ahead? The example code and difference is below.

In case of matlab:

```
b = [1, 2, 3; 1, 2, 3; 1, 2, 3]
[I, J] = find(( b > 1) & (b <= 3))
```

Gives output

```
I =                 J = 
     1                 2
     2                 2
     3                 2
     1                 3
     2                 3
     3                 3
```

In case of python:

```
b= array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])

>>> np.where((b > 1) & (b <= 3))
(array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]), array([1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both methods do provide the same answer, although order and indexing conditions are different.

Python indexing of arrays starts from `0`, like in C, whilst matlab's one starts from `1`.

Moreover, the two outputs (by matlab and numpy) do correspond one another *modulo* a permutation of the terms. Likely this is due to different indexing implementations.

You can see that matlab goes through your matrix by columns, while numpy by rows.

Comment: Thanks. If I transpose the matrix to perform the operation in Python I get the same answer as by Matlab. Just that it returns J as I now and I as J, but that is OK.